# Unexpected behavior when trying to set position of PR2 arm in Gazebo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, 
I am using Fuerte on Ubuntu 11.10. 
In Gazebo, I have been using the SetModelConfiguration method suggested [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/10999/initialize-pr2-posture-in-gazebo/) to move a PR2 arm to a certain position. It was working fine for the past several months, but recently I have gotten some unexpected behavior. When I make a service call to `/gazebo/set_model_configuration`, the robot seems to do a reset to an initial position before trying to set the requested position. This reset also seems to make the robot jump around a little.
I was wondering if anyone else has used this SetModelConfiguration method and has experienced a similar problem. 
Thank you

**Update**: When I try to move an arm through a path in small steps, the shifting is more prominent, and the robot eventually just falls through the floor.

Also, I should have posted the following code before. It is what I am using to call set_model_configuration for moving the arm.

```
set_model_config_client = rospy.ServiceProxy("/gazebo/set_model_configuration", SetModelConfiguration)
req = SetModelConfigurationRequest()
req.model_name = "pr2"
req.urdf_param_name = "robot_description"
req.joint_names = rospy.get_param("/%s/joints" % ("r_arm_controller"))
req.joint_positions = angles
rospy.wait_for_service("/gazebo/set_model_configuration")
res = set_model_config_client(req)
```

angles is the list of joint angles specifying the position of the right arm

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38220/unexpected-behavior-when-trying-to-set-position-of-pr2-arm-in-gazebo/) by [clee2693](https://answers.ros.org/users/2182/clee2693/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2012-07-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There were some bugs in 1.6.10- release that should have been patched correctly in simulator_gazebo 1.6.11, which I have just released today.  Please let me know if the problem persists.
Thanks,
John

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clee2693](https://answers.ros.org/users/2182/clee2693/) on 2012-08-07**:
It seems to be working again. Thanks.

**Comment by [clee2693](https://answers.ros.org/users/2182/clee2693/) on 2012-08-07**:
It seems to be working fine again. Thanks.

**Comment by [clee2693](https://answers.ros.org/users/2182/clee2693/) on 2012-08-07**:
It seems to be working fine again. Thanks.